# How are Linux kernel modules installed into the Android system.img

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, android

I have a question relating to building OS images for devboards such as the Hikey960 and Hikey970.

When building a Debian image one has to install the kernel modules built in the kernel into the Debian root file-system with the following command:

```
make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH="<path to root fs>"
```

I understand that this copies the modules into the root file-system so they can be insmoded at boot or whenever they are needed.

However, I do not understand how this works when building the image for Android (AOSP).

The `make modules_install` step is not done. The kernel is built and then the Image.gz is then placed in the correct place in the AOSP source. After that one has to simply type `make` and all images are generated.

What I don't understand in the AOSP process is where the built kernel modules (located in the kernel source) are installed into the Android root fs (system.img)? )

AOSP reference instructions for Hikey970: https://www.96boards.org/documentation/consumer/hikey/hikey970/build/aosp.md.html